# formvalidator.net - trying to compare two input fields

Tags: jquery, validation

Playing with formvalidator.net for doing a lot of validation.

I can not find a why to compare two input fields to make sure they are not equal.

http://www.formvalidator.net/
Looking here - I did not say any options.
If not - has anyone created a custom validator?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

used the  $.formUtils.addValidator({}) to add custom validation logic.